# eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a complex Hermitian matrix of order $n$. Let $$B=\begin{bmatrix}A & I_n\\ I_n & A^T\end{bmatrix},$$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of order $n$ and $A^T$ is the transpose (not the conjugate transpose) of $A$. Then whether we can find the eigenvalues of $B$ in terms of eigenvalues of $A$. What are the eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: @G_o_pi_i_e  \begin{align*}
|\lambda I_{2n} - B| & = 
\left|\begin{matrix}
\lambda I_n - A & -I_n \\
-I_n &\lambda I_n - A^{T} \\
\end{matrix}\right| = |(\lambda I_n - A)(\lambda I_n - A^{T})| - I_n \\
& = |\lambda I_n - A| |\lambda I_n - A^{T}| - I_n.
\end{align*}
So, the eigenvalues of $B$ seem to have some connections with $A$ and $A^T$.

Comment: @bing: The determinant is a scalar, you can't end up with a $I_n$ as part of the equation...

Comment: @bing I think copper.hat is right. You made a mistake while computing the determinant of $B$. It is a block matrix and these rules won't work.

Comment: The above progress I wrote is wrong (as  copper.hat and G_0_pi_i_e  kindly point out). Such as a block matrix 
\begin{align*}
\left|\begin{matrix} 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \end{matrix}\right| = 25 \neq \left|\begin{matrix} 2 & 0  \\ 0 & 2 \end{matrix}\right|   \left|\begin{matrix} 3 & 0  \\ 0 & 3 \end{matrix}\right| - 1.
\end{align*}